# Evaluate Gaussian-like integral, which involves an imaginary part

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration, gaussian-integral

Calculate the following formula by using complex integration. 
$$\int _{-\infty} ^{+\infty} \exp(-(x+i)^2) dx$$

It looks similar to the Gaussian-Integral
$\int _{-\infty} ^{+\infty} \exp(-x^2) dx = \sqrt{\pi}$.

I tired divide it into real part and imaginary part by using Euler Formula, but ended up with
$$\int _{-\infty} ^{+\infty} \exp(-x^2)\cos(2x)dx - i\int _{-\infty} ^{+\infty} \exp(-x^2)\sin(2x)  dx$$ the $\sin$ and $\cos$ are too tricky for me to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested ‘using complex integration’, I think using Cauchy’s integral theorem is what you are expecting.

By the substitution $u=x+i$, 
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\exp(-(x+i)^2)dx=\lim_{T\to+\infty}\int^{T+i}_{-T+i}\exp(-u^2)du$$

Consider a rectangular contour $C$, with vertexes at $(T,0),(-T,0),(T,1),(-T,1)$.

By Cauchy’s integral theorem, $$\oint_C \exp(-z^2)dz=0$$

As an exercise, prove by youself that the intergrals along the vertical lines vanishes as $T\to \infty$.

Then, 
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty}\exp(-(x+i)^2)dx=\lim_{T\to+\infty}\int^{T+i}_{-T+i}\exp(-u^2)du=\lim_{T\to+\infty}\int^T_{-T}\exp(-u^2)du=\sqrt\pi$$

Comment: Do the integrals along two vertical lines cancel each other? Because $exp(-u^2)$ is an even function?

Comment: @Rito No. Remember an even function guarantees, for example, $f(T+i)=f(-T-i)$, but not $f(T+i)=f(T-i)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{-(x+i)^{2}}dx=e\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty}e^{-x^{2}} e^{-2ix}dx$. Put $y =\sqrt 2 x$ and use the following well known formula for the characteristic function of Gaussian distribution

$\frac 1 {\sqrt {2\pi}}  \int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} e^{-x^{2}/2} e^{itx}dx=e^{-t^{2}/2}$.

Comment: The last formula, I haven't see it before. Could you give a brief proof or some intuition?

Comment: That formula is stating that the Fourier transform of a Gaussian is another Gaussian. You can prove this by splitting the complex exponential, differentiating with respect to $t$, and using integration by parts. This will yield a simple differential equation for the solution of the integral.

Comment: @Rito There are lots of places where you can find a proof. One specific place is the following: example 2, p. 275 of 'Probability' by A. N. Shiryayev. In this proof you just expand $e(itx}$ in a series and interchange the integral and the sum.